# Can you know which picture was sent from your icloud by someone else?

Tags: icloud, facebook

I was using my gf's laptop (apple), logged in my own facebook, sent a picture to myself on my facebook from her icloud. Can she notice it?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe

- If you left the downloaded photo from iCloud somewhere on her Mac, she may find out.
- If you do something with that photo (post it online etc) she will get suspicious.
- If she checks her logs and finds a photo downloaded, when she wasn't using her Mac. She could figure it out.